# How can I apply an image texture to a certain part of a mesh?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, image

I have a mesh, with 16 faces, that I ultimately show in Blender Game Engine, and want to apply separate textures to the faces via a script.

The reason behind this is I'm trying to show a detailed astrophysics skymap - currently zooming in shows pixelation, I managed to reduce the level of pixelation by increasing the texture size to 16kx16k, but I ended up using far too much RAM. I discovered that manually splitting the textures into 16 smaller chunks reduced the RAM usage (~25% of the texture is not being shown at one time, reducing RAM usage and pixelation at high zoom.

I tried to split the mesh into 32 individually textured faces and found that the rotation was much smoother and the RAM usage was further reduced.

I would obviously like to turn this workflow into a script. So far I have worked out how to texture an entire object as below, but cannot work out how to apply a different texture per face.

```
new_mat = bpy.data.materials.get('MaterialName')
    
new_mat.use_nodes = True

nodes = new_mat.node_tree.nodes
links = new_mat.node_tree.links

texture = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texture.image = bpy.data.images['Earth.png']
texture.location = 0,0

surface = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
surface.location = 300,0

output = nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
output.location = 600,0

link = links.new( texture.outputs['Color'], surface.inputs['Base Color'] )
link = links.new( surface.outputs['BSDF'], output.inputs['Surface'] )
```

Does anyone have any tips? Should I create separate objects, texture them individually then merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: You can create one material per polygon and assign all the materials *(strictly speaking: the respective index of each [material slot](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html#material-slots))* to [`MeshPolygon.material_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html?highlight=polygon%20material_index#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.material_index).

---

I'd suggest [create a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) based on the actual *face id* and the *image path* beforehand (`//` prefix is a Blender specific identifier for the [current blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6846/31447)):

```
images_per_polygon = {
    0: "//city.exr",
    1: "//courtyard.exr",
    2: "//forest.exr",
    ...
}
```

Then iterate through all [`Mesh.polygons`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=data%20polygons#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons), create a material based on the current index, add all nodes, load and assign the image to the *Image Texture* node using [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) and assign the respective *face/polygon id* to [`MeshPolygon.material_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html?highlight=polygon%20material_index#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.material_index).

[image]

Demo on how to setup one image per polygon using the *default cube* and the *built-in hdris* based on [How to load an image from disc and assign it to a newly created image texture node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201412/how-to-load-an-image-from-disc-and-assign-it-to-a-newly-created-image-texture-no) and [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python) assuming the following folder structure *(6 faces hence 6 images)*:

```
main_folder/
├── file.blend/
├── textures
    ├── city.exr
    ├── courtyard.exr
    ├── forest.exr
    ...
```

Make sure the filepaths are correct, the object is selected and run the script:

```
import bpy

# Get a reference to the object in context
# -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/239102/
obj = bpy.context.object

# Create the dictionary
# polygon id: "/path/to/current/blend/textures/image.exr"
images_per_polygon = {
    0: "//textures/city.exr",
    1: "//textures/courtyard.exr",
    2: "//textures/forest.exr",
    3: "//textures/interior.exr",
    4: "//textures/night.exr",
    5: "//textures/studio.exr"
}

# Remove all material slots from the object
# -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146719/
obj.active_material_index = 0
for i in range(len(obj.material_slots)):
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': obj})

# Create (if not present) the materials and assign them per polygon
for c, p in enumerate(obj.data.polygons):
    image = images_per_polygon.get(c)
    if image:
        # Create the material based on the name if not present 
        # -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23434
        mat_name = "Mat{}".format(c)
        mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
        if not mat:
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(mat_name)
        
        # Append the materials to the slots and assign each per polygon
        obj.data.materials.append(mat)
        p.material_index = c
        
        # Material Properties
        # -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23436/31447
        mat.use_nodes = True
        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
        nodes.clear()
        
        # Create Principled Shader node
        node_principled = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
        node_principled.location = 0,0

        # Create Image Texture node
        # -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201414
        node_tex = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
        # Assign the image
        node_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load(image)
        node_tex.location = -400,0

        # Create Output node
        node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
        node_output.location = 400,0

        # Link all nodes
        links = mat.node_tree.links
        link = links.new(node_tex.outputs["Color"], node_principled.inputs["Base Color"])
        link = links.new(node_principled.outputs["BSDF"], node_output.inputs["Surface"])
```

**Further reading**

- [Mesh's material_index is an index into what?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28589/meshs-material-index-is-an-index-into-what)
- [How to assign a material to a single face of a mesh using Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240866/how-to-assign-a-material-to-a-single-face-of-a-mesh-using-python-api)
- [How to load an image from disc and assign it to a newly created image texture node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201412/how-to-load-an-image-from-disc-and-assign-it-to-a-newly-created-image-texture-no)
- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)
- [Control Cycles/Eevee material nodes and material properties using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-eevee-material-nodes-and-material-properties-using-python)
- [Removing all material slots in one go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146714/removing-all-material-slots-in-one-go)
- [How can I get the filepaths of all default/built-in hdris?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235501/how-can-i-get-the-filepaths-of-all-default-built-in-hdris)